# Prestashop product image not showing in outlook mail

Tags: email, outlook, prestashop-1.6

I am facing a issue with product image in prestashop mail. The image appears fine in gmail but in outlook it doesn't appear. It shows red cross. On same mail shop logo is appearing in both outlook and gmail. I followed below link for solution but still the issue persists. Other mails in outlook are showing image properly only the prestashop generated mail has this issue.

https://www.slipstick.com/problems/picture-placeholders-displaying-outlook-email-messages/

Comment: proxy error? Do you have a corporate filter ?

Comment: No, by the way the issue seems to be with prestashop product image url, because if i use any other remove image url the image appears fine @Stefdelec